# Modifying response using server side scripts on Azure Mobile Services

Tags: javascript, azure-table-storage, serverside-javascript, azure-mobile-services

I have a mobile app for which I am using Azure Mobile Services as a backend.  I have a scenario in which I need to modify the elements that the client is requesting from the database.  I need to compute the rank and percentile of the record being requested, based on its best score and the best scores of all other records in the table.  I followed the [example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj631631.aspx) and wrote the below script:

```
function read(query, user, request) {
    request.execute({
        success: function(results) {
            results.forEach(function(item) {
                var totalsql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM scoreInfo";
                mssql.query(totalsql, {
                    success: function(totalresults) {
                        var totalCount = totalresults[0].Column0;

                        var moresql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM scoreInfo WHERE bestscore > ?";      
                        mssql.query(moresql, [item.bestscore], {
                            success: function(moreresults) {
                                var moreBestCount = moreresults[0].Column0;

                                item.bestrank = moreBestCount + 1;
                                item.bestpercentile = 100 - moreBestCount*100/(totalCount+1);                                
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
            request.respond();
        }
    });
}
```

But I don't see the results as expected on the client side.  I even tried logging the results on the server side but what I see on the client side doesn't match what is logged.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `mssql.query` function is asynchronous. What ends up happening is that in the `forEach` loop you're firing many asynchronous mssql requests, and right after that (without waiting for them to complete) you're callng `request.respond();` At that time you still don't have any of the responses (remember that node.js is single-threaded, so none of the responses have arrived yet).

What you'll need to do is to delay calling `request.respond()` until all the responses to the mssql calls have arrived. The code below shows one way of doing that.

```
function read(query, user, request) {
    request.execute({
        success: function(results) {
            var updateResult = function(index) {
                if (index >= results.length) {
                    // all done
                    request.respond();
                } else {
                    var item = results[index];
                    var totalsql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM scoreInfo";
                    mssql.query(totalsql, {
                        success: function(totalresults) {
                            var totalCount = totalresults[0].Column0;

                            var moresql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM scoreInfo WHERE bestscore > ?";
                            mssql.query(moresql, [item.bestscore], {
                                success: function(moreresults) {
                                    var moreBestCount = moreresults[0].Column0;

                                    item.bestrank = moreBestCount + 1;
                                    item.bestpercentile = 100 - moreBestCount*100/(totalCount+1);

                                    updateResult(index + 1); // update next result
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            updateResult(0);
        }
    });
}
```